Python Herencia Multiple con métodos con la misma firma
Supongamos que tenemos tres clases, class A, class B y class C, la clase C hereda de la clase       A y B y todas las clases tienen un método con la misma firma, y queremos acceder a dicho método con la misma firma desde el método de la clase C. Le he dado muchas vueltas y también he buscado en Google, pero no logro ver como obtener la información del método de la clase A. Pongo un ejemplo sencillo:
class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self.a = a

    def f(self) -> int:
        return self.a

class B:
    def __init__(self, b: int):
        self.b = b

    def f(self) -> int:
        return self.b

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int, c: int = 30):
        super().__init__(a)
        super().__init__(b)
        self.c = c

    def f(self) -> None:
        print(self.c, end = ", ")
        print(super().f(), end = ", ")
        print(super().f())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    c = C(1, 2, 3)
    c.f()

El output buscado sería 3, 2, 1 pero lo más cerca que he llegado es a 3, 2, 2 repitiendo el valor del método de la clase B sin alcanzar el de la clase A.
Gracias de antemano.

He encontrado la solución gracias en parte a la respuesta de René.
Publico únicamente los cambios:
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int, c: int = 30):
        A.__init__(self, a)
        B.__init__(self, b)
        self.c = c

    def f(self) -> None:
        print(self.c, end = ", ")
        print(B.f(self), end = ", ")
        print(A.f(self))


Tu error esta en class C, en el constructor:
def __init__(self, a: int, b: int, c: int = 30):
        super().__init__(a)
        super().__init__(b)
        self.c = c

Se resuelve llamando directamente a los constructores de A y B
def __init__(self, a: int, b: int, c: int = 30):
        A().__init__(self, a)
        B().__init__(self, b)
        self.c = c

El "error" se debe a unas cuestiones del MRO, esta un poco confuso así que puedes leer más aquí
Dig into Python super() and MRO

Si cambio el constructor como dices me da el siguiente error: TypeError: A.init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'

También hay que actualizar donde uses el superconstructor ya que ese es el problema.
